# go for range slice and goroutine method invocation,the logic behind

Tags: go, goroutine

The code is like the following:

```
package main

    import (
        "fmt"
        "time"
    )

    type field struct {
        name string
    }

    func (p *field) print() {
        fmt.Println(p.name)
    }

    func main() {
        data := []field{{"one"},{"two"},{"three"}}
        for _,v := range data {
            go v.print()
        }
        time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
    }
```

I know that the code is wrong,because the for loop variable is reused in the for-range loop.

When the goroutine has got the chance to launch,the value of `v` might has been modified. so the print result will be `"three,three,three"`.

But when we modify the data variable into another declaration as:

```
data := []*field{{"one"},{"two"},{"three"}}
```

the print result will be `"one ,two,three"`.

I didn't get the point of why. Does the pointer make any difference or any different mechanism is on this?

I read this from [this article](http://devs.cloudimmunity.com/gotchas-and-common-mistakes-in-go-golang/index.html#range_val_update). But the poster didn't not tell why. Or it's just a incident the output is right.

Comment: I can't see how `data` is defined different the second time.

Comment: @LutzHorn sorry for the typo and your recorrectness. the first wrong case the data is defined as      "  data := []field{{"one"},{"two"},{"three"}}" .while the new one "        data := []*field{{"one"},{"two"},{"three"}}"

Comment: Please [edit] your question and fix the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first loop, `v` is the *value* of a `field` item. Because `v` is addressable, it is automatically referenced as the pointer receiver for the `print()` method. So `v.print()` is using the address of `v` itself, and the contents of that address is overwritten each iteration of the loop.

When you change the declaration to use a `*field`, `v` is now a pointer to a `field` value. When you call `v.print()` in this case, you are operating on the value that `v` points to, which is stored in `data`, and the overwriting of `v` has no effect.

Comment: that's right,the operation is on the element stored in the `data`,but the element which is operated on is referenced by the `v`,when the loop runs ,the `v` is overwritten.when the goroutine is finally  invocated,the v has pointed to the last element.How can the `v` keep the reference to multiple whatever pointer or struct value or something else.

Comment: or maybe i miss some mechanism ,Has the golang fetched the real address which the `v` point to .or the `v` is fetched until the goroutine finally get the chance to run? the `v` value is pre-fetched or running-time fetched

Comment: @cilendeng: I don't understand your question. There's no magic going on, in Go everything is a value, and the copy happens at the time of assignment.

Comment: I got it .the parameters of a new goroutine get evaluated and passed on the current gorouine(many times the current is the  main goroutine).but it gets scheduled some time later on a new goroutine